# Is it possible to activate mana abities during the resolution of Transmute Artifact?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

If I play [Transmute Artifact](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Transmute%20Artifact), do I have to put mana into my mana pool before Transmute Artifact resolves, or can I tap my lands during Transmute artifact resolving?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can activate mana abilities whenever you are asked to pay a cost, including during the resolution of a spell or ability. You can, but don't have to activate them beforehand.**

> 605.3. Activating an activated mana ability follows the rules for activating any other activated ability (see rule 602.2), with the following exceptions:

> 605.3a A player may activate an activated mana ability whenever they have priority, whenever they are casting a spell or activating an ability that requires a mana payment, **or whenever a rule or effect asks for a mana payment, even if it’s in the middle of casting or resolving a spell or activating or resolving an ability.**

Comment: "Rulings
05/02/2021  Birgi’s first ability uses the stack and can be responded to. It isn’t a mana ability."

Comment: More generally, a triggered ability can only be a mana ability if it is triggered by another mana ability, or by mana being added to the mana pool (605.1b)